# Unable to access protected method in subclass

Tags: java, spring-jms

i cannot access a protected method in a subclass (in same package).

I am using spring-jms API's , **DefaultMessageListenerContainer** class.

In my code, i have an instance of DefaultMessageListenerContainer class, and i am trying to invoke getBeanName() method on that object, but in eclipse it says,

*"The method getBeanName() from the type AbstractJmsListeningContainer is not visible"*

As per javadoc ,this getBeanName() method is a protected method defined in superclass, 'AbstractJmsListeningContainer'.

Per my understanding, we should be able to access protected method inside subclass.
Am i missing something ?

Attaching a sample java code snippet.

[image]

Comment: Don't post pictures. Show us where you're trying to use the code you've shown.

Comment: I do not fully understand your situation; I cannot open your picture in my browser sorry. Could you please answer these questions: 1. Is DefaultMessagListenerContainer from the API you are using or it it your subclass? 2. Are you subclassing DefaultMessageListenerContainer? If so you cannot access the protected member because you can only access protected members if they your class is a direct subclass of the superclass

Comment: I posted the picture to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @univise : 1. Yes 2. No i am not subclassing

Comment: Below is my code snippet,

Comment: for(DefaultMessageListenerContainer container:containers){
    //stop container, if its running
    if(container.isRunning()){
     logger.warn("Container "+container.getBeanName() + "' was up.Bringing it down.");
     container.stop();
    }
   }

Comment: I see there is a new answer which is correct. You can access protected member only if 1. your are directly subclassing it 2. your class is in the same package. I assume your class is not in the same package?

Comment: No. Edit your question and add it there. _we should be able to access protected method inside subclass._ Which subclass? Where do you have a subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code fragment you posted is not accessing `getBeanName()` from within the subclass. It is trying to access it from client code. You'd have to define your own subclass to expose a public method to get to it:

```
class MyDefaultMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {
    public getMyBeanName() { return getBeanName(); }
}

MyDefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new MyDefaultMessageListenerContainer();
String name = container.getMyBeanName();
```

Note that you can't simply override `getBeanName()` because it is declared `final`.